# Efficient Modelling of Large Dim Tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to build a performant model for a customer activity report using fairly large datasets. If anyone can share any tips on the most efficient approach, I would appreciate it.

Specifics:

1. I have a customer base dataset in SQL warehouse which is snapshotting every month. Every customer record has a repeating unique ID with an EoM stamp. That table is about 9 million rows every month and it has about 50 attributes (demographic, product holdings etc.). This is my Dim table. This dataset is relatively stable, but every month we have between 50 and 150 thousand new customers joining and some leaving.
2. I'm linking it to the facts table which in my case is smaller than the total customer base. The facts table is about 3 million records per month and about 20 attributes.

What I'm trying to do:
Create a report with a classic star schema showing customer activity by demographic groups etc. I also need to reflect the new customers in each table (new customers in the dimension table as well as new customers in the facts table).

What I've done so far:

1. Ingested both tables using DirectQuery in full and built imported filtered versions of them to expose in the report.
2. At the moment, both tables are limited to the latest month, so the relationships between them are 1:1 and the model is performing very well.

I would like a bit of advice on the following questions:

1. Is there any point in creating an intermediary table containing only customer IDs as a go-between the two tables, or direct relationships are fine?
2. What is the best way of importing new records into the dimension table and marking some customers inactive based on their presence in that month's snapshot?
3. Is there any benefit in splitting the dimension table into several smaller dimension tables (e.g. demographic, product holdings, geo attributes etc) and linking them to the facts table individually? My concern is that in that case, I will be duplicating a high-cardinality customer ID column.
4. Any other gotchas I need to be aware of?

Comment: Typically, fact tables have many more records than dimensions - like 10x more. If you have the opposite, something is seriously wrong with your data model. Without seeing the data, I'd say that modeling customer dimension as a monthly snapshot makes no sense - it effectively turns it into a weird fact table. You should remove from the customer table all attributes that are changing every month, and place them into a fact table. This should shrink the customer dimension to a reasonable size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Reading this made me realise that I am in fact dealing with two fact tables and trying to use one of them as a dimensional filter. The fact that my current fact table is smaller is not weird at all: I am dealing with the digital activity data of the total customer base; not all customers are digitally active. As I ingest more digital activity data, the fact table will grow and eventually surpass the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple of thoughts:

1. Customer Dim - you need to decide how you want to handle changes and then implement the appropriate SCD Type e.g. if you only want the current version of the customer then implement SCD1, if you want the history then implement SCD2 etc.
2. Initially, create everything at the lowest possible level of granularity as that gives you maximum flexibility. So start with the Customer Dim and Fact(s) at the Customer level. If you decide there are useful facts at a higher grain then it is relatively simple to build them off the existing fact(s) and Dim(s) e.g. pull Customer demographic attributes into a new Dim, geographic attributes into another new Dim etc.

These are not actually very large volumes of data and, assuming that your DB is reasonably modern and is sized appropriately, there is no need to come up with any "special" design to accommodate this volume of data